# Issuing a Custom JWT After Authentication

Tags: oauth-2.0, jwt, spring-cloud-gateway

I have an application set up as follows:

Angular UI -> Spring Cloud Gateway -> Spring Boot-based Service

I am attempting to authenticate my application against a limited Oauth SSO server with ONLY the following endpoints:

- /authorize
- /token
- /userdata

The SSO does not provide an /introspect endpoint, nor does it issue JWTs.

What I would like to do is have Spring Cloud Gateway handle the authentication, but based on the result from /userdata, I would like to generate my own JWT to relay to the service.

My questions:

1. Is this possible?
2. If so, can someone give pointers or guide me to the resources that will get me started?

Comment: Do you mean you want to post user credentials to /userdata endpoint and if credentials are correct it has to respond with JWT and redirect the user to any other end point?

Comment: I'm not sure if I can explain it any better. Since my SSO does not generate JWTs, I need to use the information provided by the userdata endpoint to create my own, then use Gateway's TokenRelay to send it on to the service.

Answer (score 1):

Spring Security OAuth2.0 Client and Spring Cloud Gateway combination works well in this case.

1. Client(Angular UI) requests to the Gateway service with OAuth2.0 login URL
2. The Gateway redirects the request to Identity Provider(Such as Google) login page.
3. After user login successful Identity Provider redirects the request to the Gateway with user info.
4. On Authentication success handler(Gateway service)

   - Parse user info and save it to somewhere
   - Create access token and refresh tokens. Set them to request cookies
   - Redirect to client(Angular UI)

I don't know the reason to pass the token downstream services at this point. If there is no specific requirement then I would implement all the security related operations on the Gateway service. Such as token generation, validation etc. This way new services can be easily added without concerning about authentication and authorization.

Here is a [sample project](https://github.com/Elyorbe/sso-gateway).

Comment: The token is passed downstream because the backend service needs information like username and roles.

Comment: I've forked the project and am looking through it now.